# Bash Script involving Text Search from the Clipboard

Tags: bash

Suppose I have copied to the clipboard the following two lines of text:

> Row 1: ABC
>
> Row 2: DEF

Suppose I have a bash command `BashArgument` which takes two arguments:

> $ BashCommand arg1 arg2

Is there a way for me to create a bash script which executes `BashCommand` with the string `ABC` (from Row 1) and the string `DEF` (from Row 2) as `arg1` and `arg2`, respectively?  That is, I execute the bash script and the output is

`BashCommand ABC DEF`

How does one do this?

Comment: This is hightly **desktop dependent**. Linux desktops use a variety of clipboard apps (`klipper`, `pacellite`, etc...) along with desktop `ipc`, `dcop` or `dbus`, etc... Do you have any particular desktop in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the clipboard is platform dependant, but on Linux you can use [`xclip`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/) to access the cipboard from the terminal (you can usually install it directly with your package manager).

Assuming the clipboard contains :

> ABC
>
> DEF

Simply do :

```
BashCommand `xclip -o | sed -n 1p` `xclip -o | sed -n 2p`
```

---

**Test example :**

> > echo `xclip -o | sed -n 1p` `xclip -o | sed -n 2p`
>
> > ABC DEF

**Note:**

If your clipboard is :

> Row 1 : ABC
>
> Row 2 : DEF

Then you can use the following to remove the text before (and including) the `:` :

```
BashCommand `xclip -o | sed -n '1s/.*://p'` `xclip -o | sed -n '2s/.*://p'`
```

Or to get all the arguments at once :

```
BashCommand `xclip -o | sed 's/.*://'`
```